# Google Analytics recording event based on <a> title attribute

Tags: google-analytics

I am declaring:

```
 var title = (typeof(el.attr('title')) != 'undefined' ) ? el.attr('title') :"";
```

and then have the following:

```
else if (title.match(/^"Matching Content"\:/i)) {          
      elEv.category = "Matching Content Click"; 
      elEv.action = "click-Matching-Content"; 
      elEv.label = href.replace(/^https?\:\/\//i, '');   
      elEv.non_i = true; 
      elEv.loc = href; 
    }
```

However, using Google Analytics debugger this is not being recorded.

Any suggestions?

The complete function is:

```
if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {
  jQuery(document).ready(function gLinkTracking($) {
    var filetypes = /\.(avi|csv|dat|dmg|doc.*|exe|flv|gif|jpg|mov|mp3|mp4|msi|pdf|png|ppt.*|rar|swf|txt|wav|wma|wmv|xls.*|zip)$/i;
    var baseHref = '';
    if (jQuery('base').attr('href') != undefined) baseHref = jQuery('base').attr('href');

    jQuery('a').on('click', function (event) {
      var el = jQuery(this);
      var track = true;
      var href = (typeof(el.attr('href')) != 'undefined' ) ? el.attr('href') :"";
      var title = (typeof(el.attr('title')) != 'undefined' ) ? el.attr('title') :"";      
      var isThisDomain = href.match(document.domain.split('.').reverse()[1] + '.' + document.domain.split('.').reverse()[0]);
      if (!href.match(/^javascript:/i)) {
        var elEv = []; elEv.value=0, elEv.non_i=false;
        if (href.match(/^mailto\:/i)) {
          elEv.category = "Email link";
          elEv.action = "click-email";
          elEv.label = href.replace(/^mailto\:/i, '');
          elEv.loc = href;
        }
        else if (title.match(/^"Matching Content"\:/i)) {          
          elEv.category = "Matching Content Click"; 
          elEv.action = "click-Matching-Content"; 
          elEv.label = href.replace(/^https?\:\/\//i, '');   
          elEv.non_i = true; 
          elEv.loc = href; 
        }       
        else if (href.match(filetypes)) {
          var extension = (/[.]/.exec(href)) ? /[^.]+$/.exec(href) : undefined;
          elEv.category = "File Downloaded";
          elEv.action = "click-" + extension[0];
          elEv.label = href.replace(/ /g,"-");
          elEv.loc = baseHref + href;
        }           
        else if (href.match(/^https?\:/i) && !isThisDomain) {
          elEv.category = "External link";
          elEv.action = "click-external";
          elEv.label = href.replace(/^https?\:\/\//i, '');
          elEv.non_i = true;
          elEv.loc = href;
        }   
        else if (href.match(/^tel\:/i)) {
          elEv.category = "Telephone link";
          elEv.action = "click-telephone";
          elEv.label = href.replace(/^tel\:/i, '');
          elEv.loc = href;
        }
        else track = false;

        if (track) {
          _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', elEv.category.toLowerCase(), elEv.action.toLowerCase(), elEv.label.toLowerCase(), elEv.value, elEv.non_i]);
          if ( el.attr('target') == undefined || el.attr('target').toLowerCase() != '_blank') {
            setTimeout(function() { location.href = elEv.loc; }, 400);
            return false;
      }
    }
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you share the site with us? What does the event your pushing look like?

Comment: @Blexy, I cannot unfortunately but I have updated my question to show the complete function.

Comment: Are any of the events firing? Have you looked into using a tool such as HTTPFox or Google Debugger to look at HTTP requests?

Comment: @Blexy, I use Google Analytics Debugger (Firefox) and use the other events do fire. I just tested this again this morning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no way of testing this code without creating a jsfiddle or having you show me the site, but from a high-level, if a title does not exist, meaning it would be given "" as a value:

```
    var title = (typeof(el.attr('title')) != 'undefined' ) ? el.attr('title') :"";
```

Then, you do your else if, and attempt to match title using "" as the value of title, it probably won't work, correct?

```
     else if (title.match(/^"Matching Content"\:/i)) {          
      elEv.category = "Matching Content Click"; 
      elEv.action = "click-Matching-Content"; 
      elEv.label = href.replace(/^https?\:\/\//i, '');   
      elEv.non_i = true; 
      elEv.loc = href; 
    }
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Thanks Blexy. Turns out I didn't need \: at the end of my Matching Content string, because of course I wasn't checking for :. Silly mistake on my behalf. And yes, would've been solved if i could share my site with you.